# htaccess rewrite rule seo friendly url with query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I want SEO friendly urls with query string using .htaccess and get values in php $_GET variable

http://localhost/blog/categoryslug/postslug/?rf=1234&key=ad2312

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)/?$ /blog/detail.php?cat_slug=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

but on print_r, I get only 2 keys:

```
print_r($_GET); exit;

Array
(
    [cat_slug] => categoryslug
    [slug] => postslug
)
```

while, I need all the keys and values with in query string like this:

```
 Array
 (
    [cat_slug] => categoryslug
    [slug] => postslug
    [rf] => 1234
    [key] => ad2312
 )
```

Please help me out to resolve this

TIA

Comment: added tags and proper wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below, I added `QSA` flag to append the original incoming query to your request.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)/?$ /blog/detail.php?cat_slug=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)\?(.*)/?$ /blog/detail.php?cat_slug=$1&slug=$2&$3 [L]
```